# Why can't I connect my localhost database to cpanel phpmyAdmin

Tags: mysql, cpanel

How can I connect my localhost database to cpanel phpkyAdmin.
I'm getting that says

Error

SQL query:

Table structure for table 'banner_posts'

```sql
CREATE TABLE 'banner_posts'(
'id' int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
' title'int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
' status' varchar(40) NOT NULL, 
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

MySQL said:
`#1046 - No database selected`

Comment: `No database selected` You apparently didn't select a database.

Comment: The error isn't about the connection. It's simply saying that you need to select which database to use before running that script.

Comment: Oh okay. I've been able to fix it. Thank you